# How to Pass ResultSet in JSP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jsp

I am having an issue trying to pass my ResultSet in my JSP Page to the JavaScript Part on the Same Page.

I've tried the following

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Termine");
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
while(rs1.next()){
    String veranName = rs1.getString(1);
    String terminid = rs1.getString(2); 
    list1.add(veranName);
    list2.add(terminid);
}

String jName = (new JSONArray(list1)).toString();
String jId = (new JSONArray(list2)).toString();
```

But it didn't work.

I've also tried JQuery with stuff like

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var jIdArray = <%= jId %>
    $.each( jIdArray, function(i, l){ 
        alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){    
var jNameArray = <%= jName %>
$.each( jNameArray, function(i, l){ 
    alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
    });
});
```

Which didn't work aswell.

The JavaScript function:

```
function insertIntoTable(){
var len = jIdArray.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var vname = jIdArray[i];
    var vid = jNameArray[i];
    document.getElementById(vid).innerHTML=vname;
 }
}
```

Does anyone See my mistake or has a better Solution for my Problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your JavaScript arrays by using this way:

```
<script>

var jIdArray = new Array(

<%
   out.print("\"" + list2.get(0) + "\"");
   for(int i = 1; i < list2.size(); i++) {
      out.print(", \"" + list2.get(i) + "\"");
}
%>
)

var jNameArray = new Array(

<%
   out.print("\"" + list1.get(0) + "\"");
   for(int j = 1; j < list1.size(); j++) {
      out.print(", \"" + list1.get(j) + "\"");
}
%>
)

// work with JavaScript arrays here

</script>
```

---

Update. Not sure what you want to do, but here's a working example, if you have properly prepared JavaScript array at the server side (as shown above).

```
var jIdArray = new Array("value1", "value2");
var jNameArray = new Array("value3", "value4");

$(document).ready(function(){        
    $.each(jIdArray, function(i, l) { 
      alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
    });

    $.each(jNameArray, function(i, l) { 
      alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aleksey_Bykov/8wgdgt4g/1/) here.

Comment: If i syso my arrays before using your code, i get this: ["value1","value2"]
What does your code do? Is JavaScript not able to use this kind of Array?

Comment: I know, but i can't pass my java array to javascript.

Comment: The Thing is: I have got my ResultSet in Java Code, meaning it is being executed on serverside. If i try to use it in my Javascript Code, it doesn't work. Because the Javascript Part doesn't even find the arrays. The thing u did, is just to define them in Javascript and use them there. But i defined them with my ResultSet in the Java Part and tried to use it in Javascript. Thanks for your Effort though